# Open a shadowbox gallery of images when clicking on post thumbnail?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

It's on this page: http://www.demo.segermo.com/anlaggning/referenser-test/

Right now it's showing multiple post-thumbnails that are linked to open up a shadowbox gallery. But i only want to show one thumbnail, but still have the foreach loop run through all the attached images from the get_multi_images_src function..

See the loop i've got so far. How can i solve this problem? I know I have to get the post_thumbnail out of the loop, but i can't get it to work..

```
<?php global $shadowlink; ?>

<?php foreach(get_multi_images_src( 'thumbnail', 'large' ) as $k => $u){
$shadowlink = $u[1][0];
echo '<a rel="shadowbox[gallery1]" href="' . $shadowlink . '">';
the_post_thumbnail('insta-size', array( 'class' => "zoomer-class attachment-post-thumbnail"));
echo '</a>';
} ?>
```

Comment: Which thumbnail are you talking about in that site ?

Comment: The square little images on each post

Comment: men in black t-shirts ..That one ?

Comment: No it's the ones that look like a construction site by a big building. There are 3 but should only be one.. Try to click on them. I want only one of them and when you click on it i want it showing three images..

Comment: What you can do is : Define i=0 before foreach loop and in foreach loop, put if i==0 and at the end give increment to i.So in this way only first image will be load.Add other images in else part.And define different class to them like zoomer-class post-thumbnail and give CSS property display:none to them.

Give it try.As I am not on computer, I can not give it a try.